# Generate traincascade.exe

Tags: opencv

It's strange that haartraining in the other app's folders works just fine by taking exactly the same way. I was thinking there is a mistake in defining paths to necessary files, but it all looks fine.

Here is my setup (assuming OpenCV 2.4.5 with Visual Studio):

1. Set DLL path in environment variables:

   - Set `OPENCV245_DIR` to `C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\bin`
   - Add `%OPENCV245_DIR%` to `PATH`
2. Configure include directories:

   - `C:\opencv\opencv245\build\include`
   - `C:\opencv\opencv245\build\include\opencv`
   - `C:\opencv\opencv245\apps\traincascade`
3. Configure library directories:

   - `C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib`
4. Configure `.lib` dependencies:

   - `opencv_core245d.lib`
   - `opencv_ml245d.lib`
   - `opencv_imgproc245d.lib`
   - `opencv_objdetect245d.lib`
   - `opencv_highgui245d.lib`
   - `opencv_calib3d245d.lib`
   - `opencv_video245d.lib`
   - `opencv_features2d245d.lib`
   - `opencv_flann245d.lib`
   - `opencv_legacy245d.lib`
   - `opencv_haartraining_engined.lib`
   - `opencv_contrib245d.lib`
   - `opencv_gpu245d.lib`
   - `opencv_nonfree245d.lib`
   - `opencv_photo245d.lib`
   - `opencv_stitching245d.lib`
   - `opencv_ts245d.lib`
   - `opencv_videostab245d.lib`

I made a property sheet for both Debug and Release modes. I placed the sheets at the top as the first item under `Debug|Win32` (or `Release|Win32`) folder in the Property Sheet pane, as I read that the order of the sheets determines their precedence. In addition, the `Release` property sheet omits the `d` at the end of the `.lib` file names.

If I attempt to compile the code, I get the following output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: traincascade245, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 4/12/2013 3:11:03 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\traincascade245.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Link:
1>  
1>  Searching libraries
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_core245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_ml245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_imgproc245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_objdetect245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_highgui245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_calib3d245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_video245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_features2d245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_flann245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_legacy245d.lib:
1>      Searching             C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_haartraining_engined.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_contrib245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_gpu245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_nonfree245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_photo245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_stitching245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_ts245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_videostab245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\kernel32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\user32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\gdi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\winspool.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\comdlg32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\advapi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\shell32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\ole32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\oleaut32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\uuid.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\odbc32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\odbccp32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     10.0\VC\lib\msvcprtd.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     10.0\VC\lib\MSVCRTD.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     10.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_core245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_ml245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_imgproc245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_objdetect245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_highgui245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_calib3d245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_video245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_features2d245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_flann245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_legacy245d.lib:
1>      Searching     C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_haartraining_engined.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_contrib245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_gpu245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_nonfree245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_photo245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_stitching245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_ts245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_videostab245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\kernel32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\user32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\gdi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\winspool.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\comdlg32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\advapi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\shell32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\ole32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\oleaut32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\uuid.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\odbc32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\odbccp32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     10.0\VC\lib\msvcprtd.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     10.0\VC\lib\MSVCRTD.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     10.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_core245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_ml245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_imgproc245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_objdetect245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_highgui245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_calib3d245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_video245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_features2d245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_flann245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_legacy245d.lib:
1>      Searching     C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_haartraining_engined.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_contrib245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_gpu245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_nonfree245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_photo245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_stitching245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_ts245d.lib:
1>      Searching C:\opencv\opencv245\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_videostab245d.lib:
1>  
1>  Finished searching libraries
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall         CvCascadeClassifier::train(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class     std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class     std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class     std::allocator<char> >,int,int,int,int,int,class CvCascadeParams const &,class     CvFeatureParams const &,struct CvCascadeBoostParams const &,bool)" (?    train@CvCascadeClassifier@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?    $allocator@D@2@@std@@00HHHHHABVCvCascadeParams@@ABVCvFeatureParams@@ABUCvCascadeBoostParams    @@_N@Z) referenced in function _main
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool     __thiscall CvCascadeBoostParams::scanAttr(class std::basic_string<char,struct     std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct     std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?    scanAttr@CvCascadeBoostParams@@UAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?    $allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function _main
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool     __thiscall CvCascadeParams::scanAttr(class std::basic_string<char,struct     std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct     std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?scanAttr@CvCascadeParams@@UAE_NV?    $basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function     _main
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void     __thiscall CvCascadeBoostParams::printDefaults(void)const " (?    printDefaults@CvCascadeBoostParams@@UBEXXZ) referenced in function _main
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void     __thiscall CvCascadeParams::printDefaults(void)const " (?    printDefaults@CvCascadeParams@@UBEXXZ) referenced in function _main
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall     CvHOGFeatureParams::CvHOGFeatureParams(void)" (??0CvHOGFeatureParams@@QAE@XZ) referenced in     function _main
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall     CvLBPFeatureParams::CvLBPFeatureParams(void)" (??0CvLBPFeatureParams@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CvHaarFeatureParams::CvHaarFeatureParams(void)" (??0CvHaarFeatureParams@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CvCascadeBoostParams::CvCascadeBoostParams(void)" (??0CvCascadeBoostParams@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CvCascadeParams::CvCascadeParams(void)" (??0CvCascadeParams@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CvCascadeBoostParams::printAttrs(void)const " (?printAttrs@CvCascadeBoostParams@@UBEXXZ)
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CvParams::printDefaults(void)const " (?printDefaults@CvParams@@UBEXXZ)
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CvParams::printAttrs(void)const " (?printAttrs@CvParams@@UBEXXZ)
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall CvParams::scanAttr(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?scanAttr@CvParams@@UAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z)
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall CvCascadeImageReader::PosReader::~PosReader(void)" (??1PosReader@CvCascadeImageReader@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0CvCascadeImageReader@@QAE@XZ$0
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CvCascadeImageReader::NegReader::NegReader(void)" (??0NegReader@CvCascadeImageReader@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CvCascadeImageReader::CvCascadeImageReader(void)" (??0CvCascadeImageReader@@QAE@XZ)
1>traincascade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CvCascadeImageReader::PosReader::PosReader(void)" (??0PosReader@CvCascadeImageReader@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CvCascadeImageReader::CvCascadeImageReader(void)" (??0CvCascadeImageReader@@QAE@XZ)
1>C:\Users\knobukaw\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\traincascade245\Debug\traincascade245.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 17     unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.52
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I tried another approach using CMake software as described in http://redkiing.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/opencv-and-visual-studio-2010-with-cmake/. I did only step B-II and B-III on the webpage. Step B-II created a solution for the entire OpenCV and step B-III built it. Then I found the file I wanted (i.e. opencv_traincascade.exe) in (OpenCV solution folder created by CMake)\bin\release. It is working fine so far.